# Is it possible to forward X11 windows in a Capistrano 3?

Tags: ssh, capistrano, capistrano3, x11-forwarding, sshkit

I'm trying to forward an X11 window from a remote server. Usually I can do something like

`ssh -X some@address`

and then for example run

`feh image.jpg`

to see the `image.jpg` picture on my local machine. Is it possible to get that behaviour in Capistrano 3? I'm installing a software and it requires me to do the usual "nextnextnextfinish". I want to do something similar to (inside the `config/deploy.rb`)

`set ssh_option, {:forward_x11 => true} #doesn't work`

but it seems that `sshkit` doesn't have that option. Is there a list of the `ssh_option` for `sshkit` somewhere or is there another solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capistrano is to automate deployment using some sort of *sh script on the remote computer. Forwarding X11 Windows would make the user having to interact with the window. Therefore I ended up using a Bash script, [Sikuli](https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli) and Xvfb to automate the solution.